# How can I model a field to accep structures of the form [{names: [String!]!, scope: String!}]?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I want to add to the existing model myModel, a new field x, which can store structures of the form [{names: [String!]!, scope: String!}].

I also have to model the graphql mutation to update myModel, but I don't know how.
I thought about the following solutions, but they don't seem to be the best:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
   x = ArrayField(JSONField(default=dict), default=list, blank=True, null=True)

class MyStructure(graphene.InputObjectType):
   names = graphene.List(graphene.NonNull(graphene.String, required=True), required=True)
   scope = graphene.String(required=True)

class UpdateMyModel(ClientIDMutation):
   x = graphene.List(MyStructure)
   # x = graphene.List(graphene.JSONString) ?
   # x = graphene.List(GenericScalar)       ?
```

Comment: Isn't better to create a second model and handle this problem by creating an object for each element of your list?

This second model:

`class SecondModel(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    scope = TextField()
    my_model = ForeignKey(MyModel)`

Comment: can you please give a detailed explanation of your problem? CZ I didn't understand it.